# How does a Client call a method in a server?

Tags: c#, client-server, client

I am just learning how to use TCP client server relationships. I have been looking for hours and hours but I do not see any way that a Client can get input from the user and then the client sent a byte[] array to the server and have it do anything but compare strings, is there some way that I can have it call a method with this input? or am I missing something?

I have heard of something called serialization, though there seem to be several ways to use it, can someone point me in the right direction if this is correct?

Thanks for any reply

Comment: Do you know anything about WCF? That is what you need

Comment: Are you talking about an ajax request? - http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: i don't know if you NEED wcf.  But certainly something similar

Comment: Read WCF ...Here is a start up for you http://www.peter-urda.com/2010/09/wcf-client-server

Answer (score 0):

For a basic .NET website, I like to use the page methods for a quick easy way to make client to server calls. Consider the following aspx page and its code behind. You can expose public static server methods to javascript by adding the [WebMethod] attribute. Then you can call the function from javascript using PageMethods.NameOfFunction(). Just make sure you have a scriptmanager on the aspx page with the EnablePageMethods property set to "true".

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            var str = "bytes";
            var data = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i)
            {
                data.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
                data.push(0);
            }
            PageMethods.DoSomething(data);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptMan" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static void DoSomething(byte[] data)
    {
        //Do something with data from javascript
    }
}
```